# Windows 8.exe...?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have had windows eight and Ubuntu 13.04 dual booting and working fine(using EasyBCD)
I had created partition for Ubuntu of exactly 20GB. Some time later, after never using Ubuntu, I went into Window's partition tool and deleted my Ubuntu partition. It said it erased everything on it. I then added this 20GB onto my hardrive/windows8. I also deleted easy BCD. Everything was going fine. I turned the computer off that night and this morning it said 'windows failed to start.A recent hardware or software change might be the cause' message. It also said NTX/grub or something missing. I re-installed Ubuntu from a USB and all my data and Windows system files are there, but I am stuck running ubuntu. I believe all I need to do is find the 'windows8.exe' file and boot from that. Can someone please help here?

My error report for boot-repair is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6426199/

Comment: BTW, I have used Super-boot-manager to try to boot win8, but I cant access my hard drive in the options.

Answer (score 2):

you can try boot repair tool in ubuntu.to download type these commands in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

pres ENTER

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

press ENTER

after downloading choose recommended repair

[image]

Comment: I have tried the boot repair and it hasn't seemed to change anything. I am presented with the grub loader, it gives me a choice of ubuntu, advanced options for ubuntu, windows 8 loader and two memory tests. When I open win8, It says choose an operating system to start. The only choice is Ubuntu 13.04. When I click it it says 'windows failed to start.A recent hardware or software change might be the cause' It also says File:\NSTAutoNeoGrub1.mbr Status: 0xc000000fI also dont have the windows dis

Comment: An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6424313/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com 

You can now reboot your computer.

This error showed too

Answer (score 2):

Run a Windows recovery tool to re-install the Windows boot loader to the hard disk.

Comment: I have tried the boot repair and it hasn't seemed to change anything. I am presented with the grub loader, it gives me a choice of ubuntu, advanced options for ubuntu, windows 8 loader and two memory tests. When I open win8, It says choose an operating system to start. The only choice is Ubuntu 13.04. When I click it it says 'windows failed to start.A recent hardware or software change might be the cause' It also says File:\NSTAutoNeoGrub1.mbr Status: 0xc000000fI also dont have the windows dis

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem.  When you installed Ubuntu you replaced the bootloader.  when you uninstalled it, you removed that but didn't add the windows one back. as the previous 2 people have said, you either need to add grub back from a ubuntu(or other linux) live cd, or you need to fix the windows one using a windows recovery or install disk.  It's a good idea to keep a disk around just to fix this, as grub has a tendency to break for no good reason. (not really, it is just easy to accidentally break, and without it you are screwed without a recovery disk)

Comment: I have tried  the boot repair and it hasn't seemed to change anything. I am presented with the grub loader, it gives me a choice of ubuntu, advanced options for ubuntu, windows 8 loader and two memory tests. When I open win8, It says choose an operating system to start. The only choice is Ubuntu 13.04. When I click it it says 'windows failed to start.A recent hardware or software change might be the cause' It also says                                                              File:\NSTAutoNeoGrub1.mbr                                        Status: 0xc000000fI also dont have the windows disk

Comment: Something got screwed up with the Win8 loader then.  you should be able to find an iso for the windows  8 repair disk online, which you almost certainly need at this point.